# jQuery attr method failing to add attribute

Tags: jquery

In certain conditions I want to open links in the same window, while in others I want to open them in a new window. I have the following jQuery code:

```
if (internal) {
    jQuery(".main a").removeAttr('target');
} else {
    jQuery(".main a").attr('target', '_blank');
}
```

I have two `<a>`s contained in the "main" div. One is directly under the div while the other is buried under a couple of sub-divs. When it runs, it only adds the blank target to the first `<a>` tag. However, when I set a breakpoint through Firebug and step through it, everything works fine. Is there a reason it wouldn't work at full speed? What's the workaround?

Comment: Find the smallest HTML sample where you can reproduce this and post it here. Problem sounds a little strange and shouldn't happen really. Is the HTML valid?

Comment: i agree, it might be bad HTML syntax

Comment: No, the HTML checks out as valid. Also, there's no easy to simplify the control into something postable. I'll think about that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the particular code executed during the onload event? In jQuery you normally use `$(document).ready()` for this. E.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Do stuff onload.
});
```

Otherwise it would be executed immediately while the HTML DOM tree is still not fully built up and initialized yet.

Comment: +1 For an excellent reasoning. I agree that this sounds like this is the problem.

Comment: Excellent theory, but no. The function is run as the result of a click on the page. You click on a thumbnail image, and the "main" area displays a large image. Clicking on the image sends you to an external site or another internal page. However, there's also a button that has the same link. That's the one that doesn't work.

Comment: OK, got it. There was actually an animate to put the button into place, and at full speed it wasn't done by the time the attr function ran. The breakpoint changed the timing so everything worked. This answer is close enough that I'm going to call it right.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `each()` to step through the `A` elements:

```
jQuery(".main a").each(function() {
  $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: He shouldn't have to do that. Setting attributes effects all selected elements: http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr#keyvalue

Comment: I was sure this was going to work, but it has the same behavior. It doesn't work under normal conditions, but when I put in a breakpoint, then everything is fine.